# Will I be issued all my Boarding Passes at the Airport from GOL and KLM?

Tags: airlines, check-in, south-america, klm, airline-alliances

I am currently in Montevideo and will be  returning back to Germany tomorrow. The Flight between Montevideo to Sao Paolo is operated by GOL Linheas Aereas and from Sao Paolo to Amsterdam is by KLM.

This morning I got an email that I could check-in but from my KLM app it says
**check-in is Unavailable**.

I used the WhatsApp feature to query the KLM and they told that because the First flight is operated by GOL Linhas check-in is not possible via the App or website. I tried asking if all the boarding passes will be issued at the Montevideo Airport, but I haven't got a response for the same.

I will be reaching the airport 4 hours before the departure time and check-in but I am not sure if I will be issued all my further boarding passes. If that is the case how will the boarding passes will be issued since I have only 1.20 hours at GRU (Sao Paolo)

P.S. all the flights are booked under the same booking ID and have the same E-ticket Number.

Anyone has had such an experience while travelling with GOL and KLM under same booking code?

Comment: Same situation but reversed and I could not get GOL boarding pass until the connecting airport. Only has this type of connection once, so I don't know if it is typical.

Comment: For your situation I could say not a problem at all. If you make it at the gate of the GOL flight just ask the attendant there and everything will be fine. I just hope the other way is eaiser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP here and writing this Answer from MVD. I can confirm that all the Boarding Passes were issued till my destination once I manually checked-in at the GOL gate. It is worth noting that GOL is a partner of the Flying Blue Sky Team alliance. However when it comes to claiming miles on GOL, by default my miles from GRU to MVD were not added and I had to add them by claiming them via KLM app.

There was no hassle at all but was only asked an emergency contact number and person before issuing boarding passes.

My assumption is that irrespective of which airline you book, most of it will go through GOL and most cases the check-in is one-to-one

**case in point**
[display monitor showing all the Dky team flight number to Sao Paolo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsQ38.jpg)

All the flights from Sky Team alliance viz. Air France, KLM, Delta, GOL that go to Sao Paolo

But there are no KLM, Air France, Delta gates at MVD and only GOL.

Answer (score 2):

First of all I would try to check in online on the GOL website, if this is possible.
Since GOL is not a Skyteam member it is likely that they cannot issue the tickets for the KLM flights. In that case you will need to go to the relevant airline transfer desk (might be serviced by a partner to KLM) inside the terminal at the Sao Paolo airport, where they will issue the tickets for you. You do not need to go through immigration and exit the terminal in order to do this.

Your luggage should be forwarded automatically to your final destination since the first flight is international (for domestic flights one sometimes have to recheck the luggage at the airport where you leave the country, this however depends on the country).

Since everything is on the same booking, it is mainly the arline's responsibility that you make the connection (1.2 hours is plenty, since you do not need to go through any immigration or security). In the unlikely event that you do not make it in time, since you are flying to an EU destination with an EU-based carrier, you have the right to a nice compensation in case you are delayed/miss the connection, if the fault is due to the airline which ticketing problems surely would fall under.

If the check-in for the KLM flight has not yet started, you are still able to choose your seats, even though you cannot check-in for it online.

Comment: Just because they're not in the same alliance does not mean they wont issue tickets all the way. I recently went to Manchester from Quito with Air France, with a stop in Bogota which was provided by Avianca. Avianca and Air France are not in the same alliance, but i got ticketed all the way, also paid for my baggage at check in all the way home, which went all the way to Manchester too. I couldn't check in online like OP, had to do it at the counter. Not an issue as I needed to pay for my luggage anyway.

Comment: @BritishSam I am not saying that they cannot do it, I am just saying that it is likely that they will not. In the end it depends on the agreements between the involved companies (the likelihood that they can do it increases if they are in the same alliance since they then endeavor to make their respective systems compatible), as well as whether or not their own systems make it possible or not.

Comment: As an example, flying FUK-HND with JL and connecting to AF for HND-CDG, JAL can not issue the tickets. However, flying KE from FUK-ICN and then connecting to AF for ICN-CDG, KE can issue all the tickets since they are both in Skyteam and have made sure their systems are compatible, as well as have it in their agreements.

Comment: I get you, just my flight was booked with KLM / Air France and was from South America, so could be a similar experience.

Comment: @bjorn your answer is correct except for one little nitpick: I think you said "tickets" a few time where you meant "boarding passes" :-)